# jquery - how to add an array to a form submit?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to add an array to my form submit action. Please note I do not want to use ajax..just a regular submit after adding this "uids" parameter.

```
$("#new_meeting").live("submit", function(){
  var uids = [];
  $("span.receiver-name").each(function(){
    var uid_name = $(this).attr("id");
    var uid = uid_name.split("--")[0];
    uids.push(uid);
  })
  $("#new_meeting").append("&uids=" + uids);
});
```

This is not working since on the server side I'm not seeing the uids parameter. There is also another thing I tried looking at other posts on stackoverflow but couldn't get that to work either..here is that..

```
  var input = $("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("uids", "mydata").val(uids);
  $('#new_meeting').append($(input));
```

Has anyone done this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll give a shot before markup,

Change this

```
$("#new_meeting").append("&uids=" + uids);
```

to

```
 var input = $("<input>").attr({"type":"hidden","name":"uids"}).val(uids);
 $('#new_meeting').append(input);
```